# put partly transpared photo on top of panorama

Tags: image, transparency, gimp, rgba, alpha-transparency

What is it nessesary to do if I want to see just black edges from background image in image placed on top?
[Here](http://oi63.tinypic.com/29maskz.jpg) in the picture is what I want to create.
You can see there are edges from background panorama mountains in picture on top.
Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Does your background image already contain black edges? Then try this:

- Swap the layers so that the background image is the top layer;
- Select that layer which is now on top;
- Select All;
- Using the Select by Color tool, hold down Ctrl and click any of the black pixels to deselect all black edges and keep everything else selected (if your background image is JPEG then you will probably have to adjust the tool tolerance);
- Delete the selected area.